# Python Beginner - Having trouble with multiple choice quiz program

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python beginner here using 3.8.1 .

I am currently working on a multiple choice quiz program that works in two parts. The first part allows the users to create a series of questions+answers and save them using the Pickle module. The second part allows the users to load their save data and get quizzed by the program.

My problem is that, in the second part of the program, I want to display the multiple choice options for each question individually, but my program will end up showing the multiple choices for every single question, not just for the question currently asked by the program.

What is causing this and how can it be fixed!

Thank you for the help in advance!

```
#this is part one of the program, where the user creates and saves their data
def PartOne():
        import pickle
        import os
        from time import sleep
        os.system('cls')

        while True:
                t = input("How many questions do you have? : ")
                if t.isnumeric():
                        break
                else:
                        print("Please enter a valid number.")

        cx = list()
        ci = list()
        co = list()

        for i in range(0, int(t)):
            c = input("Please enter the question : ")
            ca = input("Please enter option A : ")
            cb = input("Please enter option B : ")
            cc = input("Please enter option C : ")
            cd = input("Please enter option D : ")
            while True:
                m = input("What option coresponds to the correct answer (a, b, c or d) : ")
                if m.lower() in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'):
                        cm = {"question": c, "answer": m}
                        cx.append(cm)
                        ch = {"option a": ca, "option b": cb, "option c": cc, "option d": cd}
                        ci.append(ch)
                        cu = {"question": cx, "answer": ci}
                        co.append(cu)
                        break
                else:
                    print("Invalid answer. Please enter «a», «b», «c» or «d»")

        while True:
                question_cm = input("Would you like to save? (yes or no) ")
                if question_cm.lower() in ('yes'):
                        pickle.dump(cx, open("Savedataone.dat", "wb"))
                        pickle.dump(ci, open("Savedatatwo.dat", "wb"))
                        pickle.dump(co, open("Savedatathree.dat", "wb"))
                        print("Saved!")
                        sleep(1.2)
                        break
                if question_cm.lower() in ('no'):
                        print ("Please save to use this information.")
                        sleep(1.2)
                        break
                else:
                        print("Invalid answer. Please enter yes or no.")

#This the second part of the program where the user uses what they inputed in part 1 to quiz themselves

def PartTwo():
        import pickle
        import random
        import os
        from time import sleep
        os.system('cls')

        while True:
                person = input("How much people will participate in this study session? : ")
                if person.isnumeric():
                        break
                else:
                        print("Please enter a valid answer.")

        for i in range(0, int(person)): 

                os.system('cls')
                cx = pickle.load(open("Savedataone.dat", "rb"))
                ci = pickle.load(open("Savedatatwo.dat", "rb"))
                co = pickle.load(open("Savedatathree.dat", "rb"))
                print("Study session will begin soon...")
                sleep(2)

                for cm in cx:
                        random.shuffle(cx)
                        print(cm["question"])
                        print(ci)
                        response = input("What was the correct answer (a, b, c or d)? : ")
                        if (response == cm["answer"]):
                                print("Good!")
                                continue
                        else:
                                print("Wrong...")
                                sleep(0.2)
                                print("The correct answer was", cm, ".")
                                continue
                        print("Study session is now over.")
                        sleep (1)
                print("Next person's study session will begin soon if needed.")
                sleep(1)
                print("Verification...")
                sleep(2.5)

        sleep(1.35)
        print("Study session is now over.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your current partTwo() fuction with:

```
def PartTwo():
        import pickle
        import random
        import os
        from time import sleep
        os.system('cls')

        while True:
                person = input("How much people will participate in this study session? : ")
                if person.isnumeric():
                        break
                else:
                        print("Please enter a valid answer.")

        for i in range(0, int(person)):

                os.system('cls')
                cx = pickle.load(open("Savedataone.dat", "rb"))
                ci = pickle.load(open("Savedatatwo.dat", "rb"))
                co = pickle.load(open("Savedatathree.dat", "rb"))
                print("Study session will begin soon...")
                sleep(2)
                questionNumber=0
                for cm in cx:
                        random.shuffle(cx)
                        print(cm["question"])
                        print(ci[questionNumber])
                        response = input("What was the correct answer (a, b, c or d)? : ")
                        if (response == cm["answer"]):
                                print("Good!")
                                questionNumber += 1
                                continue
                        else:
                                print("Wrong...")
                                sleep(0.2)
                                print("The correct answer was", cm, ".")
                                questionNumber+=1
                                continue

                        print("Study session is now over.")
                        sleep (1)
                print("Next person's study session will begin soon if needed.")
                sleep(1)
                print("Verification...")
                sleep(2.5)

        sleep(1.35)
        print("Study session is now over.")
```

I noticed that you appended every answer made in PartOne() in 'ci', but in partTwo() you just print ci without specifying which part, which prints everything.

I added a counter (questionNumber) that keeps track of the current question asked, that counter is used to specify which possible answers to give.

Comment: I'm getting this error message :     print(ci["questionNumber"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Remove the quotation marks from the word questionNumber, it makes it a string, you need an integer since it is specifying an index. In my original code you can see that it has no quotation marks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by adding quotation marks. Can you please give an example with code?